# javascript enviar multiples clasename

Tags: javascript

Necesito enviar en el evento onChange , multiples classname ( que no conozco previamente el nombre ya que se asignan mediante un loop en php )

ejemplo que utilizo para enviar un classname ( necesito enviar 3 )

```
<input type="text" class="<?php echo $fecha[$loop];?><?php echo $Mes;?>"  onChange="enviavalores(this.value,this.className);"value=""></input>
<script> function enviavalores(val,clase) { alert(clase);}</script>
```

Comment: Personalmente, probaría a añadir cada clase en un array. De manera, que más adelante puedas recorrer el array con todas las clases que estás interesado en utilizar. Más que una solución, es una propuesta jeje

Comment: Estás separando las clases con coma. En HTML las clases se separan con espacios en blanco. No sé si ese es el problema al que te refieres (no termina de quedar claro en la pregunta).

Comment: puse la coma para que se note que son 2 clases las que quiero asignar , y necesito enviar , por mas que las separe con espacio en blanco , solo envía 1 , hay forma de enviar mas de 1 clases en el evento?

Comment: Perdon si no explique el motivo , la clase 1 ( fecha ) la utilizo para tomar específicamente el valor ( en esa fecha ) , la clase 2 ( mes ) quiero tomar TODOS los valores de los input en ese mes ( esto es lo que no estoy consiguiendo ( enviar la clases MES ) ya que solo puedo enviar 1 className

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné así:

Como no permite enviar multiples className, lo más sencillo es enviar el valor en php directamente:

```
onChange="enviavalores(this.value,'<?php echo $fecha;?>','<?php echo $Mes;?>');"
```